# "Undefined Index" Error with Laravel and Intervention Image

Tags: php, laravel, forms, filesystems, intervention

Here's my file upload button:

```
<input type="file" name="image" required>
<button class="uk-button uk-button-default" type="button" tabindex="-1">Select Image</button>
```

And here's the code handling the file:

```
$largeimage = Image::make($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])->fit(1060,707)->stream('jpg');
Storage::put('public/works/' . md5($image . microtime()) . '_large.jpg', $largeimage);
```

Comment: Please add the complete error message to your question.

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["Notice: Undefined variable", "Notice: Undefined index", and "Notice: Undefined offset" using PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4261133/notice-undefined-variable-notice-undefined-index-and-notice-undefined)

Comment: Make sure you have `enctype=multipart/form-data` on your form.

Comment: https://www.quora.com/Are-Superglobals-used-in-Laravel-If-so-do-they-have-a-different-syntax

Comment: `dd($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'])` what does this return?

Answer (score 0):

You has to make a lot of changes. Its a terrible idea to store user info on public folder also Storage has as root folder the storage folder. You has to store it in storage folder

```
if($request->hasFile('image')){
    $image = $request->file('image');
    $largeimage = Image::make($image)->fit(1060,707)->encode('jpg');
    Storage::put('works/{md5(microtime())}.jpg', $largeimage);
}
```